# How to get correct status of a POD in Kubernetes using REST API

Tags: kubernetes

When a POD is terminating,  how to get correct status **Terminating** using Kubernetes **REST** API. I am not able to figure it out.
But **kubectl** always report correct status,  and it also uses REST API to do that.

What magic am I missing in REST API ? does it call two different API's and accumulate status ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not the [first person to ask this question](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22839). The answer appears to be that `kubectl` inspects `metadata.deletionTimestamp`; if this exists (and, presumably, has a non-null value) then the pod is in `Terminating` state.

For example, for a running pod:

```
$ curl -s localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/example | jq .metadata.deletionTimestamp
<empty output>
```

And then immediately after I `kubectl delete` the pod:

```
$ curl -s localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/example | jq .metadata.deletionTimestamp
"2022-01-15T15:30:01Z"
```

Comment: Link that you provided contains GO code too which is very helpful. Thanks!!